# Need help to create a new Table for PO numbers from separate tables that will not trigger a circular dependency in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dependencies, circular-dependency

I need help to create a new table that will not trigger a circular dependency in PowerBi.

I want to create a separate table with all the PO numbers from different reports that come from different ERPs, I was successful in creating the table, but PowerBi will not let me create relationships to the other tables as it creates a circular dependency.

Is there a way to create a table that will not trigger this? The other option I was considering was to use access to append all this PO numbers into a separate Access database and then pull that into PowerBi, but as I will need to refresh this table constantly it will be less time consuming to let PowerBi do it automatically.

Thanks in advance! let me know if you need further details.

This is the query that I used in DAX to create the new table, which triggered the Circular Dependency.
(The names of the source tables have been edited)

```
New Table = DISTINCT(UNION( 
                VALUES('Source Table 1'[PO- Order Id]),
                VALUES('Source Table 2'[Purchasing Document]),
                VALUES('Source Table 3'[Purchase Order]),
                VALUES('Source Table 4'[Micro Ref])
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` instead of `VALUES`...

```
New Table = DISTINCT(UNION( 
    DISTINCT('Source Table 1'[PO- Order Id]),
    DISTINCT('Source Table 2'[Purchasing Document]),
    DISTINCT('Source Table 3'[Purchase Order]),
    DISTINCT('Source Table 4'[Micro Ref])
))
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?